# Socket.io raises “TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined”

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, npm, socket.io

I am using socket.io for communicating between two servers. The problem is that after I updated the socket.io package to the last version, an issue regarding to this package persists:

1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/olficgz43zqr39e/Screenshot%202016-10-26%2018.51.11.png?dl=0
2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w92uq10ao94t84/Screenshot%202016-10-26%2018.51.34.png?dl=0

The error of the module:

```
"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" -> socket.io -> this.sendBuffer.push(packet) -> LINE: 155.
```

The issue is regarded to socket.io-client package, and the path of the second screen is:

```
socket.io-client/lib/socket.js
```

Did anyone had this issue regarding the socket.io package before?

Comment: Post relevant code *here*

Comment: The error persists in socket.io-client module, I don't think that should be relevant @Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it. If you're trying to communicate between those packages, make sure you work on the same versions for both of them. If not, some errors could appear, like the error that I wrote above. I updated both packages (socket.io-client - for the front, and socket.io - for the api), and now it works.